# Formatting doubles with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have the following situation I need help solving. I have a double that can exceed 15 digits with no decimals or can have decimals but doesn't exceed 15 digits.
Here are the conditions I need met:

- I need the double to have 6 digits of decimal precison.
- If the double exceeds 15 digits including decimals, it should turn over to scientific notation with 6 digits of precision. e.g. `1.234567E10`.
- There should be commas for numbers less than 15 digits.

e.g. if the number was `123456.382` it should be formatted as `123,456.882`.

If the number was `12345678901234567` it should be formatted as `1.234567E16`. Also if it had decimals, they should be ignored.

It tried creating a string from the double with the format specifier `%1.6g`. This works for the decimal numbers, but once the number exceeds 6 digits e.g. `100,000`, it turns into scientific notation. How can I achieve my desired results?

**Edit:** the type of scientific notation doesn't matter. i.e. I don't care whether it's `...E10` or `...e+10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the double exceeds 15 digits including decimals, it should turn
>   over to scientific notation with 6 digits of precision.

Do you mean always 6 fractional digits but if the integer part exceeds 9 digits, then go to scientific notation? If so, then here's my solution.

```
NSString *numberToString(NSNumber *number) {
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    // If number has (15 - 6) or less integer digits
    if ([number integerValue] < 1E9) {
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    } else {
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
    }

    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:6];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:6];

    return [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I fix the +0XX in the scientific notation? I don't want the leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but it does work:

```
    if ([[num stringValue] rangeOfString:@"e"].location == NSNotFound) {
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:num]);
    } else {
        formatter.positiveFormat = @"0.000000E0";
        formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundDown;
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:num]);
    }
```

If `num = NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:12345678901234567];`

Would return: `1.234567E16`

if `num = NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:123456.382];`

Would return: `123,456.382`